# Combine two queries and display result in one table?

Tags: sql

Hi guys i got stuck at one very simple issue that the following two queries are working fine but i want the result of both the queries in one table ,so what would be the possible way of joining these two so that they will combine and give result in one table,i tried `UNION` but it didnt work.Kindly tell me the solution.Thanks!

```
Select ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME,
       ITEM_DETAILS.INVOICE_NUM,
       ITEMS_MASTER.QUANTITY 
       from ITEM_DETAILS
       inner join ITEMS_MASTER 
       on ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_MODEL=ITEMS_MASTER.ITEM_MODEL

Select RATE=(CASE WHEN Discount IS NULL OR Discount=0 THEN RATE ELSE RATE-(RATE*(Discount/100))END),              
       AMOUNT=(CASE WHEN Discount IS NULL OR Discount=0 THEN AMOUNT ELSE AMOUNT-(AMOUNT*(Discount/100)) END)
       from ITEM_DETAILS
```

Comment: What is you current output, and desired output? What DBMS are you using? What happened when you used a `Union`. Why aren't you selecting the `Rate` value in your first query already? Are you trying to calculate rate?

Comment: What would be the structure of the table - what would be the columns and their data types?

Comment: Using MS Sql Server 2012,Current output is showing values in two different tables,when used `Union` it gave me error as `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists`~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is **sql server** did you try something like this

```
Select ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME,
       ITEM_DETAILS.INVOICE_NUM,
       ITEMS_MASTER.QUANTITY,
       CASE WHEN ITEM_DETAILS.Discount IS NULL OR ITEM_DETAILS.Discount=0 THEN ITEM_DETAILS.RATE ELSE ITEM_DETAILS.RATE-(ITEM_DETAILS.RATE*(ITEM_DETAILS.Discount/100))END AS 'RATE',
       CASE WHEN ITEM_DETAILS.Discount IS NULL OR ITEM_DETAILS.Discount=0 THEN ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT ELSE ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT-(ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT*(ITEM_DETAILS.Discount/100)) END AS 'AMOUNT'
       from ITEM_DETAILS
       inner join ITEMS_MASTER 
       on ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_MODEL=ITEMS_MASTER.ITEM_MODEL
```

I am not sure if you want all the rates and amount from the ITEM_DETAILS table or only those which satisfy the join condition

Comment: Yes i want exactly the same thing which you wrote thanks Karthik Ganesan :)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at both of your queries you want a combined result. In this case you do not Need UNION. You just Need to Combine the columns as below

```
Select ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME,
       ITEM_DETAILS.INVOICE_NUM,
       ITEMS_MASTER.QUANTITY,
       RATE=(CASE WHEN ITEM_DETAILS.Discount IS NULL OR ITEM_DETAILS.Discount=0 THEN ITEM_DETAILS.RATE ELSE ITEM_DETAILS.RATE-(ITEM_DETAILS.RATE*(ITEM_DETAILS.Discount/100))END),
       AMOUNT=(CASE WHEN ITEM_DETAILS.Discount IS NULL OR ITEM_DETAILS.Discount=0 THEN ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT ELSE ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT-(ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT*(ITEM_DETAILS.Discount/100)) END) 
FROM ITEM_DETAILS
       inner join ITEMS_MASTER 
       on ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_MODEL=ITEMS_MASTER.ITEM_MODEL
```